# Matching varying length in JS Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Let me explain my query with an example:

Am capturing page name from a web site. Due to design, the page name can be of varying length:
It can be

1. Data1|Data2|Data3
2. Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4
3. Data1|Data2

I need to write a Regex which comes true on all the above scenarios. I have something below shared by a previous user:

```
 /(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*)/gm;
```

The above works well when the string is always of four group, and there is a blank in between. But if I just have two values the regex fails. Can any user please guide?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your expecting? What is your expected result?

Comment: There is absolutely no way to write a pattern so that `Data3` in `Data1:Data3` could go into Group 3. Only to Group 2. See https://regex101.com/r/VZ7FeF/1.

Comment: What "blank" are you talking about?

Comment: My apology for the unclear question. Let me explain it with an example:

For e.g: am capturing page name from a web site. Due to design, the page name can be of varying length

Data1|Data2|Data3 OR Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4 OR Data1|Data2. I need to write a Regex which comes true on all the above scenarios. 

In my previous query, I had a blank field left on deliberation, e.g: Data1||Data3 OR Data1|||Data4.

Hoping some help.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for your help. I am not looking at putting Data 3 in Group 2 anyways. Let me test it out.

Comment: Can you put these info in your question? What about your last examples? Should the regex match these too?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant there but does this help? But it will only accept alphanumeric values and a space
`/([a-zA-Z 0-9]{1,}\|){1,}[a-zA-Z 0-9]{1,}/g`

Answer (score 0):

This will expect at less two Data field, and at most 4 fields

```
/(?:([^|]*)\|){1,3}([^|]*)/gm;
```

If you also want only one field (no pipe):

```
/(?:([^|]*)\|){,3}([^|]*)/gm;
```

{n,m} means allowed to repeat n trhough m times

Notice how I used `[^|]*` instead of `.*?`, so I match anything but the pipe `|`, also I used *non matching groups* `(?:)` so the groups that includes the pipes are invisible, i.e. you can get the fields as get them before